# Splitting strings in Java: lookahead and lookbehind with variable length

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to break a String in Java using numbers as delimiters, but keep the numbers. A bit of research has shown me that using the split method() from String would be appropriate, but I failed to understand how to do so. To further explain my question I'll use an example:

```
Input: 20.55|50|0.5|20|20.55

Required Output: ["20.55","|","50","|","0.5","|","20","|","20.55"]
```

By invoking the method split like the example I present below, without lookahead and lookbehind, I get the output I was expecting

```
expression.split("([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)")

Output: ["|","|","|","|"]
```

But if I try to do that with lookahead:

```
expression.split("(?=([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?))")

Output: ["2","0.","5","5|","5","0|","0.","5|","2","0|","2","0.","5","5"]
```

And by using lookbehind I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index
>   22 (?<=([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?))

Can anyone explain me this behaviour, and suggest a solution?

PS: I know I can use the '|' to break the string, but this is just a silly example, I actually need a much more complex regex...

**EDIT:**

Seems to be impossible to do what I want because of the length of the delimiters. Since I was looking for a solution to a smaller problem, which I could then use to the remaining of the exercise, I will rephrase to see if there's a turnaround, like the one found in the second and third answers:

I want to break a String in Java containing an arithmetic expression, and keep all its items. For example:

```
Input: 20.55 * 0.5 ** cos(360) + sin 0 * cos 90 + 1 * sin (180 + 90) * 0
Output: ["20.55", "*", "0.5", "**", "cos", "(", "360", ")", "+", "sin", "0", "*", "cos", "90", "+", "1", "*", "sin", "(", "180", "+", "90", ")", "*", "0"]
```

PSS: please note that I have to use '**' for the exponentiation.

**EDIT 2**
Following the answer given by anubhava, a solution was found to break an arithmetic expression on all its items

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\*\\*|sin|cos|tan|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|[-()+*/%]" );
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(expression);

while(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: To reword your question, would it be correct to say you want to find all numbers in a string?  If so, why not do a regex that looks for numbers as opposed to using `split`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question... I need to do it in Java. Is there another way to do it in Java with regular expressions ?

Comment: Using `split` typically means you want the stuff between the delimiters.  You can do what you are asking, but I would use a `Pattern` with `Matcher` and `Matcher.find()` to get the numbers.  Not saying that's better, just more "normal," maybe.

Comment: You are correct, the problem was solved using precisely the approach you just mentioned! The question now contains the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex for splitting:

```
String[] toks = "20.55|50|0.5|20|20.55".split( "(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])" );

for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("%s%n", tok);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY7qW1/5)

---

**Update:**

You can use this regex for **matching** your tokens:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "sin|cos|tan|\\d+(?:\\.\d+)?|[-()+*/%]" );
```

You can then use `Matcher#find()` method in a while loop to get all the matched tokens.

Comment: That solves the given example, but doesn't answer the question... I have to treat the following delimiters the same way: "**", "cos", "sin"... What exactly is the '\d' ?

Comment: `\d` matches `[0-9]`. Your edit has made this question **totally different** from earlier. `sin/cos/tan` etc are not numbers and go against earlier ask that says **I want to break a String in Java using numbers as delimiters**

Comment: Thank you, It is working now :)

You are correct, my edit has made the question totally different, but I was trying to break the problem in a smaller problem, and if I would get a solution for the initial question, I would be able to solve it out by myself. 

But from my understanding, the following regex was matching the '|', which was not what I wanted. I edited the question so that a good answer for it could appear, and it did show up.

    (?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't define lookbehinds with variable length. `+`, `*` and `?` all match a variable amount of characters. This is a limitation of most regex engines.

You can have lookaheads with variable length however. But in your case, this wont do the job, because lookarounds don't consume already matched data.

You want something that does:

```
([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)\\K
```

What `\K` does is just throw away what was already matched. Therefore, you will still split by certain positions and won't repeat yourself with the floating numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(?<=\d)(?=\|)|(?<=\|)(?=\d)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sG0hD7/1)

In Java:

```
public class RegexTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String string = "20.55|50|0.5|20|20.55";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\|)|(?<=\\|)(?=\\d)")));
    }
}
```

with result:

> [20.55, |, 50, |, 0.5, |, 20, |, 20.55]

**EDIT**

To use other characters as delimeters to include "*", "sin" ,etc., you can change regex to:

```
(?<=[0-9a-z*])(?=\|)|(?<=\|)(?=[0-9a-z*])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sG0hD7/2)

where `[0-9a-z*]` means digit, letter or "*". If you want to include other characters, just add it to character class, like `[0-9a-z*E]`, etc.

Comment: As I replied to @anubhava, that doesn't answer the question in its entirety, just solves the given example. What exactly is the '\d' and how can I use it to parse other delimiters, like "**", "cos", "sin"?

Comment: @rsy `\d` means digit, if you want to match also other characters, pleas provide examples, it is quite important

Comment: By using this expression: [^\\d.], you are matching everything that is not a number or a dot, which in the given example is the same as matching just for the '|'. I will then assume there's no way to do what I want, and edit the original question

Comment: @rsy I did't use `[^\\d]` here, it is comment to anubhava, no me ... I used `\d` and `|` to match place between them

Comment: @rsy and solution from my edited answer? it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the help @m.cekiera, but it still doesn't work! I think you misunderstood what I wanted. Please check the new example, in the edited original question