# Java regex: Replacing dynamic substrings

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a String containing static tags that looks like this:

`mystring = "[tag]some text[/tag] untagged text [tag]some more text[/tag]"`

I want to remove everything between each tag pair.  I've figured out how to do so by using the following regex:

`mystring = mystring.replaceAll("(?<=\\[tag])(.*?)(?=\\[/tag])", "");`

The result of which will be:

`mystring = "[tag][/tag] untagged text [tag][/tag]"`

However, I'm unsure how to accomplish the same goal if the opening tag is dynamic.  Example:

`mystring = "[tag parameter="123"]some text[/tag] untagged text [tag parameter="456"]some more text[/tag]"`

The "value" of the `parameter` portion of the tag is dynamic.  Somehow, I have to introduce a wildcard to my current regex, but I am unsure how to do this.

Essentially, replace the contents of all pairings of `"[tag*]"` and `"[/tag]"` with empty string.

An obvious solution would be to do something like this:

`mystring = mystring.replaceAll("(?<=\\[tag)(.*?)(?=\\[/tag])", "");`

However, I feel like that would be hacking around the problem because I'm not really capturing a full tag.

Could anyone provide me with a solution to this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Your regex already contains (.*?) that is what you need to put before ]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've tried this, but this does not allow me to compile.  The error is "repetition not allowed inside lookbehind."

Comment: @LanceToth Look behind can't be non fixed width

Comment: Fair enough. If the tag is always dynamic, you could look for a ] preceded by anything but g `(?<=[^g]\])(.*?)(?=\[\/tag])` (mind, I removed some of the escape characters)

Comment: If you changed square brackets to angle brackets and wrapped the string in a root tag you could use an XML parser. In fact, why don’t you just use XML instead of your only-slightly mutated form of XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching the whole tag with content and replacing with the opening/closing tags without content :

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\[tag[^\\]]*\\][^\\[]*\\[/tag]", "[tag][/tag]")
```

[Ideone test](https://ideone.com/eJmO0g).

Note that I didn't bother conserving the tag attributes since you mentionned in another answer's comments that you didn't need them, but they could be kept by using a capturing group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  The only issue with this is it will strip the contents of _any_ tag, not specifically tags with the name "tag".

Comment: @Andrew I thought `tag` was a placeholder, I should have been more careful reading your question. Let me fix that :) Oh, and should I go along and just delete the tag as you suggested you were doing afterward in the other question's comments?

Comment: It's my mistake.  I shouldn't have used the word "tag" because it made the situation confusing.

Comment: @Andrew Here, fixed. Much easier than what I had originally done ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I've got it.

I thought long and hard about what @AshishMathew said, and yeah, lookbehinds can't have unfixed, lengths, but maybe instead of replacing it with nothing, we add a `]` to it, like so:

```
mystring = mystring.replaceAll("(?<=\\[tag)(.*?)(?=\\[/tag])", "]");
```

`(?<=\\[tag)` is the look-behind which matches `[tag`

`(.*?)` is all the code between `[tag` and `[/tag]`, which may even be the parameters of the tag, all of which is replaced by a `]`

When I tried this code by replacing the match with `""`, I got `[tag[/tag] untagged text [tag[/tag]` as the output. Hence, by replacing the match with a `]` instead of nothing, you get the (hopefully) desired output.

So this is my **lazy** solution (pardon the regex pun) to the problem.

Comment: This definitely works and exists in some state sort of in between capturing the whole tag and the obvious solution I suggested, lol.  I guess I can probably do this.  If no one posts an answer that allows me to just replace with emptystring, I'll mark this one the answer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Andrew Anytime! Also, I'll try to post an answer that works without replacing the match with `]` :)

Comment: @Andrew I've refined the code a little, but still not sure how to do it without replacing with `]`

Comment: @Andrew Here's [a link to a question about lookbehinds with variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538744/splitting-strings-in-java-lookahead-and-lookbehind-with-variable-length), and hopefully you'll figure out a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Cofeehouse Coder Than you!

Comment: I just noticed this answer replace `[tag parameter="123"]` by `[tag]`, @Andrew is it expected?

Comment: That's fine.  I actually have an additional step that replaces all occurrences of `[tag][/tag]` with emptystring afterward.  I just wasn't sure how to include that in the previous regex.

Comment: By the way, as your answer insinuates, the word "tag" is required.  There is another answer on this question that replaces any type-of-tag's contents with emptystring which I do not want to do.

Comment: You get my upvote for effort, but using lookarounds for this task is way overkill and very inneficient ;) Lookarounds are very rarely needed and should be avoided when they aren't (I'd even go as far as saying they should be avoided when they are needed in favour of a regex-less solution, but this might be a bit excessive :) )

Comment: @Aaron Understood. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder I did mark the other answer correct, but thanks again for your assistance!